# Decoding Microsoft True Type Font Files

Tags: c++, c, gcc, decode, truetype

I am working on an embedded platform (STM32F407) with a TFT LCD as a display (480x800px) and would like to make my user interface somewhat customizable to the end user. I figured the best source of fonts would be windows compatible as their the most common.

My current implementation uses my own custom drawn font in a binary format and a descriptor table giving the character width and ascii value but having to draw my own font bit by bit is tedious.

I would like to read in a True Type Font file from an SD card and be able to use the different sized glyphs inside it but I have not seen a strait forward implementation on how to actually achieve this magic. Can somebody point me to a good c/c++ example of what I am looking for?

Even better as a way to iron out the kinks I would like to make a simple gcc command line program that will print out my input with a selected font using '#' as pixels. That way I can just worry about implementation and not any other random bugs that might pop up.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: IIRC [ttf](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/tt/ttf_spec/ttch02.doc)s don't necessarily contain [raster data](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/RM06/Chap6bdat.html) (a few may do for 8pt or less sizes to improve readability). Are you willing to add hinting and bezier rendering capabilities to your application? :)

Comment: Yeah, TTF is primarily a vector format, and a rather complex one at that. While it's obviously possible to write a renderer, you're likely to be much better off just using an image file to define the font, or using a bitmap font format like FNT (Windows) or BDF (UNIX).

Comment: @duskwuff Wow I think I reinvented the wheel again. [AngelCode's BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) & [Useage](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/330742-quick-tutorial-variable-width-bitmap-fonts/) is EXACTLY what I had just wrote except using Microsoft paint one pixel at a time and doing math for each char... Thanks for the note of the FNT format heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As duskwuff says: TTF is primarily a vector format, would need to write a renderer. Better off using an image file to define the font, or using a bitmap font format like FNT (Windows) or BDF (UNIX).

Here is my answer to my own question: [AngelCode's BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) & [Useage](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/330742-quick-tutorial-variable-width-bitmap-fonts/). This makes choosing selective characters from the installed char set, mix in a font and exports an image with a map file to each character. Simple to use.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can use the [Freetype](http://www.freetype.org/index2.html) library.

Comment: Ask the OP how much non-removable flash storage he has available on his [STM32F407](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-44837/l/stm-datasheet-for-stm32f407-mcu) kit first. :)